# How do I stop a site from redirecting me away because I don't have JavaScript enabled?

Tags: browser, redirection, noscript

When using NoScript, some sites are detecting I don't have JavaScript and redirecting me to another page?

How do I prevent them from doing this redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, you can use the NoScript extension, then follow these steps:

1. Open Options...
2. Open the Advanced tab.
3. Open the Untrusted tab.
4. Check "Forbid META redirections inside  elements".

This type of redirect uses a META refresh (meta http-equiv="REFRESH").